# Which texture do I bind to when implementing multi-texturing?

Tags: android, opengl-es, multitexturing

I have been having some issues getting multi-texturing to work using OpenGL ES 1.1. I have two PKMs - one with RGB's and one for alphas and I am trying to combine the two as below:

```
            int rgbTexture = textureId[0];

            gl.glActiveTexture(GLES10.GL_TEXTURE0);
            gl.glBindTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, rgbTexture);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GLES11.GL_MODULATE);

            ETC1Texture etcTexture = ETC1Util.createTexture(inputStream);
            ETC1Util.loadTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, GLES11.GL_RGB, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, etcTexture);

            int alphaTexture = textureId[1];

            gl.glActiveTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE1);
            gl.glBindTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, alphaTexture);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GLES11.GL_COMBINE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_COMBINE_RGB, GLES11.GL_REPLACE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_SRC0_RGB, GLES11.GL_PREVIOUS);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GLES11.GL_SRC_COLOR);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_MODULATE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_SRC0_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_TEXTURE);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_SRC_ALPHA);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_SRC1_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_PREVIOUS);
            gl.glTexEnvf(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GLES11.GL_OPERAND1_ALPHA, GLES11.GL_SRC_ALPHA);

            InputStream inputStreamAlpha = fileIO.readAsset(fileName + "_alpha.pkm");
            ETC1Texture etcAlphaTexture = ETC1Util.createTexture(inputStreamAlpha);
            ETC1Util.loadTexture(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, GLES11.GL_RGB, GLES11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, etcAlphaTexture);
```

One of the problems that I am having is I don't know which texture ID to bind to when rendering this multi-texture and if I should make GL_TEXTURE0 or GL_TEXTURE1 active when rendering. The code above is from the load() method within my Texture class. On startup, I load all of the necessary textures using the code above. I then keep a reference to these Texture objects while I still need them and when I want to render them, I bind to the ID of the rgbTexture (as shown above) and I make GL_TEXTURE0 active. Is this correct? Should I be binding to the alphaTexture's ID? Should GL_TEXTURE1 be active when rendering? Or both? Or is multi-texturing supposed to happen at render time? Ideally I am looking for a solution that combines these textures into one at startup and then when rendering, I just bind to this one combined texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, think of texture units (GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXTURE1), as layers, each texture layer can have any texture assigned to it (texture id). This should be done when rendering and not when loading the textures.

When rendering you need to:

```
for each used texture unit
 Activate texture unit using glActiveTexture;
 glBind the appropriate texture;

Blend the textures using Modulate, Add etc;
And finally draw your object;
```

Comment: There is no programmable pipeline in OpenGL ES 1.1, so it would be impossible for FFP to be deprecated. Texture Combiners are a *very early* attempt to introduce some rudimentary programmability to fragment processing. Nobody uses them unless the hardware does not support actual fragment shaders, they are extremely tedious to work with... but for Riva TNT / GeForce 256/2 class hardware and many embedded GPUs they are all that are available :-/ The original Doom 3 engine actually has a code path that uses register/texture combiners for lighting instead of shaders.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for the clarification I didn't notice the OP is using ES1.1 I thought it was OpenGL1.1

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I know about texture combiners check my answer here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71246/is-multitexturing-really-just-using-more-than-one-texture/71248#71248

Comment: @concept3d thanks for the great answer, I finally understand how this works. I got it working, problem is that the PKM file that stores the alphas that I want to combine with the color values of the other PKM, does not store its values in its alpha channel :( The alpha value seems to be stored in the RGB channels with black representing full transparency and white representing full opaqueness. I can't figure out how to use a non-alpha source during the alpha combine step of my multi-texturing. If you know how to do this, I asked another question that perhaps you could answer.

Comment: @concept3d the question is here btw: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-rgb-channels-of-a-texture-as-the-alpha-channel-when-ap